# IIS Performance Issue due the Threads in ASP.Net Application

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-8

We have ASP.Net Web Application deployed in IIS. When we have more incoming requests, throughput of App getting decreased. Based on analysis, it appears to be related to Threads.

We have tried following configurations to improve threads in IIS.

In the C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config

```
   <system.web>
        <processModel maxWorkerThreads="100" maxIoThreads="100" minWorkerThreads="1"
            minIoThreads="1" />
   </system.web>
```

In Web.Config:

```
 <httpRuntime minFreeThreads="8" minLocalRequestFreeThreads="8"
      targetFramework="4.6.2" />
```

In machine.config:

```
<system.web>
    <processModel autoConfig="false"
         maxWorkerThreads = "100"
         maxIoThreads = "100"
         minWorkerThreads = "50"
         minIoThreads = "50" 
         />
```

Even with all the above configurations, there is NO improvements. It will be great if anyone can help in resolving the same.

Comment: If there are too many requests, changing your configuration won't help much. You just need a farm with more servers.

Comment: "Based on analysis, it appears to be related to Threads." What kind of analysis? Reveal that. Likely that you were on the wrong track and drew a wrong conclusion. Changes to ASP.NET thread model is only useful in certain cases (burst load and so on), but it won't resolve others (deadlocks and so on).

Comment: Thanks @LexLi. Our model is Web app gets requests and it puts the request data into Queue(5 queue). And from Queue, it process the request. When we simulate 500 users load, it could process only 200 requests/ second  from the Queue. Moment the incoming request stops, the processing increases to 400 request/ second. Like you said, analysis can be wrong. Hence trying to get help in this forum.

Comment: The description is still not ideal for me to understand your actual design. But red flags are there if requests won't yield to responses in a short enough period of time, and changes to machine.config won't help that. What's the average processing time of each requests? If they take long (even a few seconds) to finish, due to database queries/file IO and others, you really should consider redesign the system to use a more suitable mechanism. For example, browser side triggers a heavy operation, and poll its progress. SignalR is better there than raw request/response.

Comment: It is recommended to reproduce this issue and capture dump files. The dump file contain a snapshot of all your current requests and their status. You can see what they were doing or waiting. By analyzing the dump file, you should have more idea about which property should be modifed.